# How to connect from Openvpn server to one of it's clients

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

So I am doing this DIY project where I want to connect some old android phones as surveillance cameras in a country house. Phones are connected to mobile internet without a static IP address (and without any possibility to forward ports).

As a solution I set up Openvpn server using https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn and connected my phones to VPN.

Everything works fine and I am able to reach cameras if I connect both cameras and my desktop PC to VPN. But at the same time I need to be able to reach cameras over VPN from the server. Currently I am not able even to ping the client.

How can I achieve this? I suppose I may need to somehow forward the traffic to certain subnet.

Long story short: I am not able to connect to VPN client from the server, but able to connect to the client from another client.

Thanks

Comment: This *seems* more about the routing rules being configured on the OpenVPN client - if I remember correctly, you have to enable client-to-server and client-to-client routing. A little off topic here though, as I don't believe this is pertinent to Ubuntu.